# PHP - Group Strings By Similarity / Substring

Tags: php, string, substring, grouping, similarity

### PHP

Hi, I have been struggling with this problem for awhile and can not find a solution to it and was wondering if anyone could help.

I need to group similar strings for example:

### Input

Slim Aluminium HDMI Lead, 1m Blue
Slim Aluminium HDMI Lead, 2m Blue
Slim Aluminium HDMI Lead, 3m Blue
Frozen Kids Headphones with Volume Limiter
XLR Plug to Socket Lead, 3m
XLR Plug to Socket Lead, 6m
Monster High Kids Headphones with Volume Limiter
TMNT Kids Headphones with Volume Limiter
Batman Kids Headphones with Volume Limiter
1-Gang Cable Entry Brush Wall Plate White/White Brushes 50 x 45mm
2-Gang Cable Entry Brush Wall Plate White/White Brushes 50 x 100mm
1-Gang Cable Entry Brush Wall Plate White/Black Brushes 50 x 45mm
2-Gang Cable Entry Brush Wall Plate White/Black Brushes 50 x 100mm
Slim Aluminium HDMI Lead, 5m Blue
Slim Aluminium HDMI Lead, 7.5m Blue
6.35mm (1/4") Mono Jack to Jack Guitar Lead, 5m Orange
XLR Plug to Socket Lead, 0.5m
XLR Plug to Socket Lead, 1m
XLR Plug to Socket Lead, 2m

### Output (Grouped In Array)

Slim Aluminium HDMI Lead, 1m Blue
Slim Aluminium HDMI Lead, 2m Blue
Slim Aluminium HDMI Lead, 3m Blue
Slim Aluminium HDMI Lead, 5m Blue
Slim Aluminium HDMI Lead, 7.5m Blue

XLR Plug to Socket Lead, 0.5m
XLR Plug to Socket Lead, 1m
XLR Plug to Socket Lead, 2m
XLR Plug to Socket Lead, 3m
XLR Plug to Socket Lead, 6m

1-Gang Cable Entry Brush Wall Plate White/White Brushes 50 x 45mm
2-Gang Cable Entry Brush Wall Plate White/White Brushes 50 x 100mm
1-Gang Cable Entry Brush Wall Plate White/Black Brushes 50 x 45mm
2-Gang Cable Entry Brush Wall Plate White/Black Brushes 50 x 100mm

Frozen Kids Headphones with Volume Limiter
Monster High Kids Headphones with Volume Limiter
TMNT Kids Headphones with Volume Limiter
Batman Kids Headphones with Volume Limiter

6.35mm (1/4") Mono Jack to Jack Guitar Lead, 5m Orange

Comment: What did you try so far? Did you use PHP's similar_text() function?

Comment: I also just found out about the levenshtein() function too, might be worth an investigate

Comment: @Paul I have tried similar_text() but can not get it to work properly, results can be random.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a better solution, I should have picked one word at a time and found matches, removing the matches from the pool, rather than trying to sort and then do it one after each other.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Update: I've found a better solution*

I've never played with php's similar_text() function but I thought I'd give it a shot...

```
$array = explode(PHP_EOL,'Slim Aluminium HDMI Lead, 1m Blue
Slim Aluminium HDMI Lead, 2m Blue
Slim Aluminium HDMI Lead, 3m Blue
Frozen Kids Headphones with Volume Limiter
XLR Plug to Socket Lead, 3m
XLR Plug to Socket Lead, 6m
Monster High Kids Headphones with Volume Limiter
TMNT Kids Headphones with Volume Limiter
Batman Kids Headphones with Volume Limiter
1-Gang Cable Entry Brush Wall Plate White/White Brushes 50 x 45mm
2-Gang Cable Entry Brush Wall Plate White/White Brushes 50 x 100mm
1-Gang Cable Entry Brush Wall Plate White/Black Brushes 50 x 45mm
2-Gang Cable Entry Brush Wall Plate White/Black Brushes 50 x 100mm
Slim Aluminium HDMI Lead, 5m Blue
Slim Aluminium HDMI Lead, 7.5m Blue
6.35mm (1/4") Mono Jack to Jack Guitar Lead, 5m Orange
XLR Plug to Socket Lead, 0.5m
XLR Plug to Socket Lead, 1m
XLR Plug to Socket Lead, 2m');

$output = array();
while( empty( $array ) === false )
{
  $currentWord = array_shift( $array );
  $currentGroup = array( $currentWord );
  foreach( $array as $index => $word )
  {
    if( similar_text( $word, $currentWord, $percentage ) and $percentage > 80 )
    {
      $currentGroup[] = $word;
      unset( $array[ $index ] );
    }
  }
  $output[] = $currentGroup;
}

print_r($output);
```

---

```
// Array
// (
//     [0] => Array
//         (
//             [0] => Slim Aluminium HDMI Lead, 1m Blue
//             [1] => Slim Aluminium HDMI Lead, 2m Blue
//             [2] => Slim Aluminium HDMI Lead, 3m Blue
//             [3] => Slim Aluminium HDMI Lead, 5m Blue
//             [4] => Slim Aluminium HDMI Lead, 7.5m Blue
//         )
// 
//     [1] => Array
//         (
//             [0] => Frozen Kids Headphones with Volume Limiter
//             [1] => Monster High Kids Headphones with Volume Limiter
//             [2] => TMNT Kids Headphones with Volume Limiter
//             [3] => Batman Kids Headphones with Volume Limiter
//         )
// 
//     [2] => Array
//         (
//             [0] => XLR Plug to Socket Lead, 3m
//             [1] => XLR Plug to Socket Lead, 6m
//             [2] => XLR Plug to Socket Lead, 0.5m
//             [3] => XLR Plug to Socket Lead, 1m
//             [4] => XLR Plug to Socket Lead, 2m
//         )
// 
//     [3] => Array
//         (
//             [0] => 1-Gang Cable Entry Brush Wall Plate White/White Brushes 50 x 45mm
//             [1] => 2-Gang Cable Entry Brush Wall Plate White/White Brushes 50 x 100mm
//             [2] => 1-Gang Cable Entry Brush Wall Plate White/Black Brushes 50 x 45mm
//             [4] => 2-Gang Cable Entry Brush Wall Plate White/Black Brushes 50 x 100mm
//         )
// 
//     [4] => Array
//         (
//             [0] => 6.35mm (1/4") Mono Jack to Jack Guitar Lead, 5m Orange
//         )
// 
// )
```

---

Assoc array edit

```
$products = array(
  array('id'=>'A','name'=>'Slim Aluminium HDMI Lead, 1m Blue'),
  array('id'=>'B','name'=>'Slim Aluminium HDMI Lead, 2m Blue'),
  array('id'=>'C','name'=>'Slim Aluminium HDMI Lead, 3m Blue'),
  array('id'=>'D','name'=>'1-Gang Cable Entry Brush Wall Plate White/White Brushes 50 x 45mm'),
  array('id'=>'E','name'=>'2-Gang Cable Entry Brush Wall Plate White/White Brushes 50 x 100mm'),
  array('id'=>'F','name'=>'1-Gang Cable Entry Brush Wall Plate White/Black Brushes 50 x 45mm'),
  array('id'=>'G','name'=>'2-Gang Cable Entry Brush Wall Plate White/Black Brushes 50 x 100mm'),
  array('id'=>'H','name'=>'Slim Aluminium HDMI Lead, 5m Blue'),
  array('id'=>'I','name'=>'Slim Aluminium HDMI Lead, 7.5m Blue')
);
$output = array();
while( empty( $products) === false )
{
  $currentProduct = array_shift( $products );
  $currentGroup = array( $currentProduct );
  foreach( $products as $index => $product )
  {
    if( similar_text( $product['name'], $currentProduct['name'], $percentage ) and $percentage > 80 )
    {
      $currentGroup[] = $product;
      unset( $products[ $index ] );
    }
  }
  $output[] = $currentGroup;
}
print_r($output);
```

Comment: throw in a `sort($array)` before the while loop processing for a nice result.

Comment: this works great, thank you so much :)

Comment: sorry to bother you again, how would I adapt this to work with an assoc array instead of just the array of strings at the start, e.g. if the string names were inside a child index for example: [0] => Array([id] => 4578, [name] => Slim Aluminium HDMI Lead, 1m Blue)

Comment: Se my last edit :)