# Finding Similarities in strings, then grouping in new array with other data

Tags: php

I believe I have a complex issue which I'm struggling to find a solution for, and for the life of me I can't seem to achieve it.

I need to run an analysis on **thousands** of bank transactions to find similarities in their descriptions.

To start, I have an array of transactions, that are grouped by month, here's is a small sample:

```
$sample_transactions = array(
  ['Oct_2017']=>array(4) {  
    [0] => array(2) {
      ["desc"]=>string(55) "INTERNET TRANSFER CREDIT FROM 34345555 REF NO 21283322"
      ["amount"]=>string(4) "1290"
    }
    [1] => array(2) {
      ["desc"]=>string(55) "INTERNET TRANSFER CREDIT FROM 34345555 REF NO 8765876"
      ["amount"]=>string(4) "1000"
    }
    [2] => array(2) {
      ["desc"]=>string(55) "INTERNET TRANSFER CREDIT FROM 785674556 REF NO 46312212"
      ["amount"]=>string(4) "2500"
    }
    [3] => array(2) {
      ["desc"]=>string(55) "INTERNET TRANSFER CREDIT FROM 785674556 REF NO 977553"
      ["amount"]=>string(4) "4000"
    }
  }
  ['Nov_2017']=>array(4) {  
    [0] => array(2) {
      ["desc"]=>string(55) "PHONE TRANSFER CREDIT FROM 65765544 REF NO 123444"
      ["amount"]=>string(4) "879"
    }
    [1] => array(2) {
      ["desc"]=>string(55) "EFTPOS JKL REV JANES HAIR MELBOURNE VIC AU"
      ["amount"]=>string(4) "200"
    }
    [2] => array(2) {
      ["desc"]=>string(55) "INTERNET TRANSFER CREDIT FROM 785674556 REF NO 46312212"
      ["amount"]=>string(4) "3200"
    }
    [3] => array(2) {
      ["desc"]=>string(55) "INTERNET TRANSFER CREDIT FROM 785674556 REF NO 977553"
      ["amount"]=>string(4) "6039"
    }
  }
);
```

Using the sample transactions above, the desire is to look for similarities in their **desc**, then group them together, add a count of how many there were, and increment the total figure.

### Here is an example of the desired data:

```
Oct_2017
=================================================================
|        Desc.                            |  Amount   |  Count  | 
=================================================================
|  TRANSFER CREDIT FROM 34345555 REF NO       2290         2    |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
|  TRANSFER CREDIT FROM 785674556 REF NO      6500         2    |
=================================================================

Nov_2017
=================================================================
|        Desc.                            |  Amount   |  Count  | 
=================================================================
|  TRANSFER CREDIT FROM 785674556             9239         2    |
=================================================================
```

If you notice from the two tables of data, it does the following:

- Skips the string if it only occurs once
- Groups strings if they occur twice, but, they **can** have differences somewhere, e.g. Reference number at the end of the string
- Increments the "amount" for that group
- Increments the "count" for each time an occurrence was found.

**Edit**: These transactions are provided to us from a third party source and saved in our Mysql DB, so the strings could literally be *anything*. This means we can't have a collection of strings to look for, because we don't know what we are looking for. We need to highlight the "patterns" in the transactions rather than things we are looking for.

**Edit2:** Some more sample strings could be:
`RETURNED CREDIT FROM Mr Nobody 9392 JKK freight ACCOUNT CLOSED`
`RETURNED CREDIT FROM Mrs Somebody Melbourne Aus INVALID ACCOUNT NUMBER`
`VISA CREDIT HERTZ GOKKO JIMBO 14/08 AU AUD`
`EFTPOS DEP Medicare Benefit`
`DIRECT CREDIT CBA TRANSFER`
`BPAY REV 3535333 KLM RENEW 4823`
`AGENT DEPOSIT 87`
`ANZ ATM PORTLAND 26 NOTHING ST PORTLAND VIC`
`DIRECT CREDIT DONTY BENEFITS 23423322 EYWQ`

### Methods I've tried:

1 - I tried [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45479413/php-group-strings-by-similarity-substring) to compare strings, however, using `similar_text()` is not specific enough - it results in groups being made which shouldn't be as it's just based on the similarity percentage, and doesn't group based on characters like required.

2 - I tried querying from the database using `ORDER BY desc ASC` which obviously orders them quite well, but includes everything, and doesn't group them like the desired result.

Comment: Is this tied up to a database? Considering it's financials, I'd assume so. In that case, you case use something like SQL's `SELECT * FROM x WHERE desc LIKE` clause. Otherwise you can use PHP's `in_array()` method.

Comment: I think it is time to rethink the DB structure.  Why not isolate the values that you want to match, and assign them their own column for easy access?  I'm thinking a `FROM_id` column would do.  If you don't want to change anything, we can probably hack something together for you -- in which case I recommend that you setup a little sqlfiddle for us to play with.  We'll just need to chop out the substring between `FROM` and `REF`.

Comment: Re: @obsidian-age
Thanks, yes it's in a MySQL database, first thing I thought when in_array (or something similar), however, we don't know what we are looking for. This is an analysis and those strings could be absolutely anything, so I wouldn't be able to create an array of strings to look for.

Comment: Re: @mickmackusa
Cheers! We're not sure what it is we are looking for. We're analysing regular occurrences in their transactions so the strings could be absolutely anything, so a table with FROMs wouldn't really be possible. Thanks, I'll set up a sqlfiddle.

Comment: You may need to use a human-managed lookup array to search for and count (chunks of words) substrings previously known to occur.  These strings need to be broken down somehow.

Comment: Just so you know, this question risks being too broad and may be closed.

Comment: I've got an idea.   I'll post something when I get home.   (Admittedly it makes assumptions about your strings.  The more variations you provide, the better answers we can offer you.)

Comment: Thanks @mickmackusa I've just edited my answer to include samples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bad news is: php doesn't offer anything out of the box to do this kind of process.

The good news is: you can roll your own and modify it as you learn more about what you want to call "similar".  As your bespoke method matures, its accuracy will ascend ever closer to 100%. Use the "leftovers" to discover similarities that can be built into the code.

I hope this is enough to give you some traction:

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d1656d8151a940ae983a211e91905c9942867f16))

```
$sample_transactions=[
    'Oct_2017'=>[
        ["desc"=>"INTERNET TRANSFER CREDIT FROM 34345555 REF NO 21283322","amount"=>"1290"],
        ["desc"=>"INTERNET TRANSFER CREDIT FROM 34345555 REF NO 8765876","amount"=>"1000"],
        ["desc"=>"INTERNET TRANSFER CREDIT FROM 785674556 REF NO 46312212","amount"=>"2500"],
        ["desc"=>"INTERNET TRANSFER CREDIT FROM 785674556 REF NO 977553","amount"=>"4000"],
        ["desc"=>"PHONE TRANSFER CREDIT FROM 65765544 REF NO 123444","amount"=>"879"],
        ["desc"=>"EFTPOS JKL REV JANES HAIR MELBOURNE VIC AU","amount"=>"200"],
        ["desc"=>"INTERNET TRANSFER CREDIT FROM 785674556 REF NO 46312212","amount"=>"3200"],
        ["desc"=>"INTERNET TRANSFER CREDIT FROM 785674556 REF NO 977553","amount"=>"6039"],
        ["desc"=>"RETURNED CREDIT FROM Mr Nobody 9392 JKK freight ACCOUNT CLOSED","amount"=>"123"],
        ["desc"=>"RETURNED CREDIT FROM Mrs Somebody Melbourne Aus INVALID ACCOUNT NUMBER","amount"=>"124"],
        ["desc"=>"VISA CREDIT HERTZ GOKKO JIMBO 14/08 AU AUD","amount"=>"1234"],
        ["desc"=>"EFTPOS DEP Medicare Benefit","amount"=>"999"],
        ["desc"=>"DIRECT CREDIT CBA TRANSFER","amount"=>"1050"],
        ["desc"=>"BPAY REV 3535333 KLM RENEW 4823","amount"=>"1175"],
        ["desc"=>"AGENT DEPOSIT 87","amount"=>"100"],
        ["desc"=>"ANZ ATM PORTLAND 26 NOTHING ST PORTLAND VIC","amount"=>"200"],
        ["desc"=>"DIRECT CREDIT DONTY BENEFITS 23423322 EYWQ","amount"=>"300"]
    ]
];

foreach($sample_transactions as $mo_year=>$trans_array){
    foreach($trans_array as $trans){
        if(!$key=strstr($trans['desc'],' FROM ',true)){ // declare $key if no ' FROM ' try something else
            if(strpos($trans['desc'],'DIRECT CREDIT')===0){  // try 'DIRECT CREDIT' at start of string
                $key='DIRECT CREDIT';
            }else{
                $key=$trans['desc'];  // if all attempts fail, default to fullstring value
            }
        }
        if(!isset($groups[$mo_year][$key])){
            $groups[$mo_year][$key]=['Amount'=>$trans['amount'],'Count'=>1];  //initialize the row
        }else{
            $groups[$mo_year][$key]=[
                'Amount'=>$groups[$mo_year][$key]['Amount']+$trans['amount'],  // do the sum
                'Count'=>++$groups[$mo_year][$key]['Count']  // increment by 1
            ];
        }
    }
}

// split results into two groups based on Count value
foreach($groups as $mo_year=>$rows){
    foreach($rows as $desc=>$sums){
        if($sums['Count']<2){
            $singletons[$mo_year][$desc]=$sums;
        }else{
            $similarities[$mo_year][$desc]=$sums;
        }
    }
}

echo "Attempted Consolidation:\n";
var_export($groups);
echo "\n\nSimilarities:\n";
var_export($similarities);
echo "\n\nThe leftovers to review and try to isolate relevant similarities\n";
var_export($singletons);
```

Output:

```
Attempted Consolidation:
array (
  'Oct_2017' => 
  array (
    'INTERNET TRANSFER CREDIT' => 
    array (
      'Amount' => 18029,
      'Count' => 6,
    ),
    'PHONE TRANSFER CREDIT' => 
    array (
      'Amount' => '879',
      'Count' => 1,
    ),
    'EFTPOS JKL REV JANES HAIR MELBOURNE VIC AU' => 
    array (
      'Amount' => '200',
      'Count' => 1,
    ),
    'RETURNED CREDIT' => 
    array (
      'Amount' => 247,
      'Count' => 2,
    ),
    'VISA CREDIT HERTZ GOKKO JIMBO 14/08 AU AUD' => 
    array (
      'Amount' => '1234',
      'Count' => 1,
    ),
    'EFTPOS DEP Medicare Benefit' => 
    array (
      'Amount' => '999',
      'Count' => 1,
    ),
    'DIRECT CREDIT' => 
    array (
      'Amount' => 1350,
      'Count' => 2,
    ),
    'BPAY REV 3535333 KLM RENEW 4823' => 
    array (
      'Amount' => '1175',
      'Count' => 1,
    ),
    'AGENT DEPOSIT 87' => 
    array (
      'Amount' => '100',
      'Count' => 1,
    ),
    'ANZ ATM PORTLAND 26 NOTHING ST PORTLAND VIC' => 
    array (
      'Amount' => '200',
      'Count' => 1,
    ),
  ),
)

Similarities:
array (
  'Oct_2017' => 
  array (
    'INTERNET TRANSFER CREDIT' => 
    array (
      'Amount' => 18029,
      'Count' => 6,
    ),
    'RETURNED CREDIT' => 
    array (
      'Amount' => 247,
      'Count' => 2,
    ),
    'DIRECT CREDIT' => 
    array (
      'Amount' => 1350,
      'Count' => 2,
    ),
  ),
)

The leftovers to review and try to isolate relevant similarities
array (
  'Oct_2017' => 
  array (
    'PHONE TRANSFER CREDIT' => 
    array (
      'Amount' => '879',
      'Count' => 1,
    ),
    'EFTPOS JKL REV JANES HAIR MELBOURNE VIC AU' => 
    array (
      'Amount' => '200',
      'Count' => 1,
    ),
    'VISA CREDIT HERTZ GOKKO JIMBO 14/08 AU AUD' => 
    array (
      'Amount' => '1234',
      'Count' => 1,
    ),
    'EFTPOS DEP Medicare Benefit' => 
    array (
      'Amount' => '999',
      'Count' => 1,
    ),
    'BPAY REV 3535333 KLM RENEW 4823' => 
    array (
      'Amount' => '1175',
      'Count' => 1,
    ),
    'AGENT DEPOSIT 87' => 
    array (
      'Amount' => '100',
      'Count' => 1,
    ),
    'ANZ ATM PORTLAND 26 NOTHING ST PORTLAND VIC' => 
    array (
      'Amount' => '200',
      'Count' => 1,
    ),
  ),
)
```

Comment: My answer is not the golden bullet that I am sure you would have liked to received (there isn't one).  I am afraid I can't help with the business-logic.  If you have questions about how to extract substring with regex or non-regex, I can help you with that.

Comment: This looks incredibly promising! I realise it's going to mature, a lot! But for now this looks great. I'll get back to you with how it turned out. Thank you @mickmackusa

Comment: Just got home.  I'm going to fix something.

Comment: thanks @mickmackusa - I've implemented this into the application and although, as you said, it's not a golden bullet, it's the best solution we have so far. We've already developed it further and will continue to do so. Thank you! Answer accepted.

Comment: I think this is a cool project.   If you have any small related questions or would like a brief review leave me a comment with a demo link.